# Calculating size of pages and page tables

Tags: architecture, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

A physical address is 32 bits and the virtual address is split as 10 bits 'off-set',2 bits 'byte addressability', 20 bits being left for identifying the page.

What size are the pages and the page tables?

I believe its:

2^10 = 1024.

The ones that are reserved pages are 2^2 = 4

I am not sure on how to use the addressbility though...

Thanks again guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me tell you:

In the architecture that you use, you will use 2<sup>20</sup> pages, and offset will help you identify the word location in a page. So page size is 2<sup>10</sup>. What is the 2 bits of addressability? It is the addressability of bytes in a word => you have 4 bytes in a word and these 2 bits maps to the byte locations in your word.

Comment: Just wondering how did you know that there are 4 bytes in a word? Thanks though for the explanation thus far

Comment: @Banned if you have 2 bits to address bytes in a word, it means you can address 2^2 bytes in a word. 2^2 = 4

Comment: @CarsonMyers actually it is vice versa situation: If you have 32 bits it means you have 4 bytes. Byte count doesn't come from architectural decisions. Only architectural decision is whether you want to address them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing mechanism is is similar to looking for a word in the dictionary, first, find the chunk of words with just the 1st letter matching and then keep narrowing down. Similarly, 1st 20 bits to locate the page , next 10 bits to locate the word the particular page and last 2 bits for the byte in the word.